# How do I write a division function in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, division

This is my first week using scheme, and I'm stuck on a simple problem. I want to write a function that does simple integer division. This is what I've written and I'm getting a bad syntax error. Any help on how to fix this and make the code work?

```
    (define divisible-by
     (lambda (a b)
     (if (= a b)
     (display #f))
                   )
     (if (= (remainder a b) 0)
     (display #t)
     (else
     (display #f))
    )
)
```

Comment: The identation is completely off, but I guess you are using DrRacket. If you do `Racket > Reindent all` (CTRL + I) then you'll see that you have closed the lambda half way inn and gived `define` 3 operands instead of the expected 2. Also using `display` will print a result, but return a undefined value. Thus as a function your `divisible-by` will not return different values.

Comment: I think you're confusing the "output" that a procedure returns to its caller with the "output" that the user of a program sees printed.

Comment: You might also be confusing Scheme with some other language which uses `else` in that manner and mistaking `display` for `return`. (And you're almost certainly expected to use `and` and `not`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that you won't be able to submit but which shows you how you might approach this.

I assume you are not allowed to simply use division, so one way to divide *n* by *d*, assuming *n* is a natural number and *d* is a non-zero natural number, is to repeatedly subtract *d* from *n* while incrementing a result, *r*, until you get a number which is less than *d*, which is the remainder.  Here is that:

```
(define (div/rem n d)
  ;; Return the quotient and remainder of n by d
  ;;
  ;; You should perhas check they are naturals here, and that d is non-zero
  ;;
  (define (div/rem-loop m r)
    (if (< m d)
        (values r m)
        (div/rem-loop (- m d) (+ r 1))))
  (div/rem-loop n 0))
```

There are more concise ways of writing this (named `let` is the obvious one).